# Elasticsearch: Document not being added to index with custom mapping

Tags: python, elasticsearch, mapping

I am crawling websites using `Scrapy`. I want to store the data from each crawl directly to `Elasticsearch`. I was able to find a pipeline written just for this:
https://github.com/jayzeng/scrapy-elasticsearch/blob/master/scrapyelasticsearch/scrapyelasticsearch.py 
`Elasticsearch` applies custom mapping to fields if not mentioned otherwise. I created an index on my localhost with a custom mapping (code attached below).
The index is successfully created and the mapping is also applied. Now when I try to store data in that particular index, no document is added to it. However, if I specify an index that has not been created via custom mapping, documents are added to it.

Code for custom mapping:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch() 

mapping = {
     "mappings": { 
     "properties": { 
        "name": { 
           "type":  "text" 
       }, 
       "last_updated": { 
          "type": "text" 
       }
}}}

es.indices.create(index='my-index', ignore=400, body=mapping)
```

Comment: Please share a document you try to insert. Also check the .refresh interval value.

Comment: maybe it is just updated because of same _id ?

Comment: @DejanMarić it's not updated because it never makes in `Elasticsearch` in the first place.

Comment: @LeBigCat the document I'm trying to insert has the following structure:

```Python
{'description': 'Ready-to-wear Lawn bell-bottom with  embroidery',
 'discount': 30.0,
 'discount_price': 1400.0,
 'is_available': True,
 'name': '19-t5-bell-bottom-e-2110',
 'price': 2000.0,
 'product_id': '90A079E1-FF4A-4A58-A27F-570064245072',
 'product_type': 'product',
 'provider': 'fishry',
 'quantity': 8,
 'sku': 'RW02612-LRG-WHT''}
```

Comment: Please retry using double quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking this into for a couple of hours, I finally realized what the problem was. The item that I was indexing was a custom object that I had created and therefore was **NOT** JSON serializable by default. I simply typecast it into `dict` and it worked like a charm.